# Reviewboard doesn't work after I update the website directory permisson

Tags: review-board

I installed Reviewboard on centos7 through 'yum -y install ReviewBoard'. I cannot access the website after all set. It asks me to update the website directory permission(Manual server updates required). But I have already updated the permission which the owner and group is 'apache'.

I check the logs and no error.

Anyone can help?? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did not set the appropriate SELinux booleans or else I installed ReviewBoard to a directory where Apache doesn't have SELinux access permission.

So I disabled SELinux and all worked.